# Static variable memory destruction

Tags: memory, variables, scope, static-variables

A static variable is defined in a function.Can v destroy its memory outside that function?

Comment: What language are you asking about?

Comment: What is `v`?  Is that the static variable?

Comment: It was about C language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about C, then no you can't "destroy its memory" - all your static variables are going to be around for as long as your program is running.

Comment: Strictly speaking - for as long as the module (it could be a .dll) is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "destroy its memory"?

If you mean 'free' the memory, the answer is no.

If you mean overwrite it, the answer is yes (a pointer to the variable can be given to something outside the function that 'owns' it, or a common bug could trash the memory).

Comment: I meant free the memory...Thanks